# Vertically align navigation

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a navigation bar which I want to fully align vertically (also when I scroll).

I know from another thread that you can vertically align with:

```
#container
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: -200px 0;
}
```

but how do I vertically align a navigation bar so that I don't have to hardlink the size?

Google mostly has old technigues and hard links. If I have missed a link which has this topic please remind me!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use table tag to accomplish this task, you can structure your navigation better with this.
Like:

```
<table id="tblMain" width="80%">
<tr><td colspan="2">Your Header </td></tr>
<tr><td width="30%">
<table id="tblNavigation">
  <tr><td><a href="#">Navigation Link 1</a> </td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="#">Navigation Link 2 </a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="#">Navigation Link 3</a> </td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td width="70%"><div id="mainDiv"></div>
</td>
<td colspan="2">Your footer </td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Hi, this would work but I would avoid tables for design stuff. Do you have something without tables but with the same features?